# Перестал работать скрипт после добавления label к input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть рабочий скрипт который добавляет класс блоку в зависимости от выбора радиокнопки в каждом блоке радиокнопок. Но после того как я обернул input в label для стилизации этих кнопок работать скрипт перестал. Я, к сожалению, полный ноль в javascript и jquery, поэтому прошу помощи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я напортачил?
Сам код ниже:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle-up', 'parallelogram', 'parallelogram-green', 'triangle-up-green', 'circle-green', 'square-green', 'square-black']

  function showShape() {
    const checkedIndexes = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => $(n).index());
    const iShape = checkedIndexes[0] + checkedIndexes[1] * 3;
    console.log(iShape);
    $('#box').removeClass(shapes.join(' ')).addClass(shapes[iShape])
  }
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(showShape)
  showShape()
}
```

```css
#box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.square {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: black;
}

.circle {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: red;
}

.triangle-up {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: green;
}

.parallelogram {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parallelogram-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.triangle-up-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.circle-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2DD14A;
}

.square-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2C5A77;
}

.square-black {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #53076F;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fcc71;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px hsla(150, 100%, 50%, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>ВЫБЕРИТЕ ПЛАН:</h1>
  <div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество человек:</h2>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label for="1"><input id="1" name="form-1" type="radio" checked>1</label>
          <label for="2"><input id="2" name="form-1" type="radio">2</label>
          <label for="3"><input id="3" name="form-1" type="radio">4</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество дней:</h2>
      <div>

        <form>
          <label for="4"><input id="4" name="form-2" type="radio" checked>3</label>
          <label for="5"><input id="5" name="form-2" type="radio"> 5</label>
          <label for="6"><input id="6" name="form-2" type="radio"> 7</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правильно добавили `<label>`, он не должен оборачивать тег, к которому относится, он привязывается по `id`, при этом индексы элементов необходимо пересчитать

Правильно так:

```
<input id="3" name="form-1" type="radio">
<label for="3">4</label>
```

Вот код:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle-up', 'parallelogram', 'parallelogram-green', 'triangle-up-green', 'circle-green', 'square-green', 'square-black']

  function showShape() {
    const checkedIndexes = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => ($(n).index()+1)/2-1);
    const iShape = checkedIndexes[0] + checkedIndexes[1] * 3;
    console.log(iShape);
    $('#box').removeClass(shapes.join(' ')).addClass(shapes[iShape])
  }
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(showShape)
  showShape()
}
```

```css
#box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.square {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: black;
}

.circle {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: red;
}

.triangle-up {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: green;
}

.parallelogram {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parallelogram-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.triangle-up-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.circle-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2DD14A;
}

.square-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2C5A77;
}

.square-black {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #53076F;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fcc71;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px hsla(150, 100%, 50%, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>ВЫБЕРИТЕ ПЛАН:</h1>
  <div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество человек:</h2>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input id="id1" name="form-1" type="radio" checked>
          <label for="id1">1</label>
          <input id="id2" name="form-1" type="radio">
          <label for="id2">2</label>
          <input id="id3" name="form-1" type="radio">
          <label for="id3">4</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество дней:</h2>
      <div>

        <form>
          <input id="id4" name="form-2" type="radio" checked>
          <label for="id4">3</label>
          <input id="id5" name="form-2" type="radio"> 
          <label for="id5">5</label>
          <input id="id6" name="form-2" type="radio"> 
          <label for="id6">7</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Igor да я думал об инпуте, хрень написал

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но вы пробовали выполнить такой код? Он совершенно также не работает.

Comment: @Newageman починил =), там с индексом была ошибка и Ваш css написан так, что лэйбл должен идти после инпута

Comment: Теперь не работают первые 2 кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши радио-кнопки стали единственными элементами, содержащимися в соответствующих родителях - `label`-ах. Поэтому `$(n).index()` все время возвращает `0`.

https://api.jquery.com/index/#index

```
const checkedIndexes = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => 
  $(n).closest("label").index());
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const shapes = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle-up', 'parallelogram', 'parallelogram-green', 'triangle-up-green', 'circle-green', 'square-green', 'square-black']

  function showShape() {
    const checkedIndexes = $('form :checked').toArray().map((n, i) => $(n).closest("label").index());
    const iShape = checkedIndexes[0] + checkedIndexes[1] * 3;
    console.log(iShape);
    $('#box').removeClass(shapes.join(' ')).addClass(shapes[iShape])
  }
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(showShape)
  showShape()
}
```

```css
#box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}

.square {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: black;
}

.circle {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: red;
}

.triangle-up {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: green;
}

.parallelogram {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parallelogram-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.triangle-up-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: orangered;
}

.circle-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2DD14A;
}

.square-green {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #2C5A77;
}

.square-black {
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 48px;
  width: 446px;
  height: 374px;
  background-color: #53076F;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #eee;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2fcc71;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: hsla(150, 75%, 50%, 1);
  color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px hsla(150, 100%, 50%, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>ВЫБЕРИТЕ ПЛАН:</h1>
  <div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-right: 20px;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество человек:</h2>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label for="1"><input id="1" name="form-1" type="radio" checked>1</label>
          <label for="2"><input id="2" name="form-1" type="radio">2</label>
          <label for="3"><input id="3" name="form-1" type="radio">4</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div style="display: inline-block;margin-bottom: 40px;">
      <h2>Количество дней:</h2>
      <div>

        <form>
          <label for="4"><input id="4" name="form-2" type="radio" checked>3</label>
          <label for="5"><input id="5" name="form-2" type="radio"> 5</label>
          <label for="6"><input id="6" name="form-2" type="radio"> 7</label>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br></div>
    </div>


    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но, к сожалению, код, всё также, не работает.

Comment: @Newageman Работает. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.